# Error when logging in Ionic 3 + Angular 4 + Firebase mobile application - Error: signInWithEmailAndPassword failed: "email" must be a valid string

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm trying to create a simple chat application with Firebase. Registering users in firebase works. When trying to log in with one of the registered usernames (email address), I get this error message:

Runtime error: username is not defined

Users give their username in login.html and I'd like to use this username later on the chat.html page. This is the next page coming up after logging in.

login.html:

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Login
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>Username</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]= "username"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>Password</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]= "password"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  </ion-list>

  <div padding>
    <button ion-button (click)="signInUser()">Sign in</button>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

login.ts:

```js
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, AlertController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { ChatPage } from '../chat/chat';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})

export class LoginPage {

  username: string= '';
  password: string= '';

  constructor(private fire: AngularFireAuth, public navCtrl: NavController, private alertCtrl: AlertController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad LoginPage');
  }

  alert(message: string) {
    this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Info!',
      subTitle: message,
      buttons: ['OK']
    }).present();
  }

  signInUser() {  
    username= this.username;
    message= this.message;
    
    this.fire.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.username, this.password).then(data=> {
    console.log('got data', this.fire.auth.currentUser);
    this.alert('Success! You\'re logged in');
    this.navCtrl.push(ChatPage);

    }).catch(error => {
      console.log('got an error', error);
      this.alert(error.message);
    })
    console.log('Would sign in with ', this.username, this.password)
  }
}
```

Comment: please include the source codes here instead of links to images on external websites

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as **text** ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing.  Images should only be used, *in addition to text in code format*, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove ".value" for the variables `this.username` and `this.password` from your `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` function and check

Comment: Thank you! Now I get this error: Runtime error: username is not defined

Comment: could you update your login.ts code here?

Comment: I updated it. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: Pls upvote/mark it as an answer if it helped

Comment: It didn't help, I still get an error :(